# Using PrintWriter and OutputStream

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream, printwriter

I am creating a project with struts and I have a problem using Jasper IReports. I want to export some info into a pdf file and I keep getting the java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been call... Exception due to openning a ServletOutputStream in my code when the page already opens a PrintWriter.

The code is in the model (so it is not in the jsp, it's in a java file), as it follows:

```
    public void handle(HttpServletResponse res, Connection connection, String path)throws Exception{
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    try {

        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(path);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, null, connection);
        res.setContentType("application/pdf");
        res.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        out = res.getOutputStream();
        out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

I have checked the connection, the path and the HttpServletResponse and are all working fine.

I'm very newbie with Jasper Reports as well as with coding stuff into PDF so you can -correctly- suposse that I have a minimal idea of what I am doing here and that, obviously my code is copy/pasted from somewhere through the net.

I have tried to use PrintWriter instead of OutputStream, transforming bytes into a String and using the PrintWriter.append(String) method (allthought is not String is CharSequence), but it doesn't extract the data into the PDF.

I have also tried to get the PrintWriter, close it to open the OutputStream (didn't work) or flush it (neither).

Any help with a solution to use any out that could show the data in a pdf would be great.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: who is opening the PrintWriter?

Comment: The JSP file attempts to open PrintWriter when it starts. So when I send the control to the jsp file via ActionMapping.findforward the JSP opens the PrintWriter and starts to show the JSP. I solved this by not going anywhere with my findforward. So there is no JSP file to be loaded (there is nothing to be loaded) and the PDF code (via OutputStream) goes to the page without loading a jsp file and becouse of that, without loading PrintWriter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would be useful to see the stack trace.

You might try running a sanity check first though: Modify that code to simply write a static string (hello world) to the ServletOutputStream and set content type to text/html. As that should work fine:

```
public void handle(HttpServletResponse res, Connection connection, String path)throws Exception{
ServletOutputStream out = null;
try {
    byte[] bytes = "hello world".getBytes();
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    res.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    out = res.getOutputStream();
    out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

HTH

Comment: Indeed, this code it works perfectly. I do not understand it, since I thought that you couldn't have a OutputStream and a PrintWriter both open. Is it that by setting content type to "text/html" it somehow overrides the PrintWriter?

Comment: No i think only one can be open:

`http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()`

Are you attempting to call getWriter() after writing to the outputstream? If you are then that's why you're getting the illegalstateexception.

Comment: I think I understand now, As the outputStream writes the pdf, the program still finishes going to the actionmapping.findforward (to my jsp). And the jsp writes with the PrintWriter. I think that there is the problem and why now I can see my pdf and have the Exception raised anyway. I could try not to go anywhere with the actionmapping so there is no Exception for using PrintWriter.

Comment: And there it is, this is my lat stacktrace:
15-ene-2010 14:09:48 org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping findForward
ADVERTENCIA: Unable to find '' forward.

There is no Exception; but I wonder how this programing fits in the good practices...   (as I suposse it simply doesn't)

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

- PrintWriter isn't going to work if you are working with a binary stream (PDF are binary)
- The illegal state might occur if there is client side timeout or disconnect.  A packet trace of the process will tell you a lot (even if you can't read them well).  Look at WireShark or what is available for your platform.  Its worth your time to learn at least a little bit about what happens at the wire level.
- Make sure the data you are getting back from the report generate is actually a pdf.  Write it to a file and attempt to open.
- Some situations need you to set the http length header before writing to the stream otherwise they give up when the data starts to show.  Might be necessary here.

Comment: Thanks! I have done a simple Java proyect (not webapp) and tried to create a PDF File, my jrxml seems to work.
I will search for what happens in the wire level.
My report is fairily short (around 200 charaacters) I don't think the URL is getting too big for it...

Answer (score 1):

How exactly is the code invoked? Judging from the stacktrace it look like that you're running the Java class with the `handle` method using *scriptlets* inside a JSP file (the `inicio2.jsp` to be precise). After that the Java class has written the report to the `OutputStream`, the JSP file would continue with outputting the remnant of the file itself (including whitespace!), which would implicitly invoke the `getWriter()` to write it to response. Exactly that would cause an `IllegalStateException` as you're facing now when the `getOutputStream()` is already been called before in the Java class.

It's good that Java code is been placed in a Java class, but that doesn't mean that you may still use JSP to invoke it. The JSP should not contain any single line of Java code. JSP itself is as being a view technology part of the output. To fix this all, just have a Struts action class (or a `HttpServlet`) which you can invoke by a HTML `<form>` or `<a>`.

Comment: The code is invoked in a Java file in a class of my own that is called in an Action of my own and the JSP calls it throgh a struct-config-xml like any other MVC using struts.

The problem is more or less solved (see simonlord's comments): The code attempted to write a .pdf using OutputStream in a page while at the end of that code it tried to redirect to inicio2.jsp after writing the .pdf. Of course the jsp uses PrintWriter and there is the problem. I solved it by not redirecting the code to anywhere (in the findforward).
Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Own answer:

I have put in the path a jrxml that actually connects to the database and gets some real data out and suddendly it worked, the PDF opened in mozilla, but the Exception keeps happening. I do not know how I can throw and exception (I have debugged and the Exception happens in the same place) and be able to see the PDF.

So I can only keep searching for what actually happens here. I will answer with anything I find (probably on monday).

Thanks simonlord and Jim Rush for your help! :)

Edit: By the way, here is the stacktrace (it's in Spanish, if needed I will translate anything you don't understand):
Edit again: Seems I didn't copy the '1' in the 15th-Jan-2010... could create confusion about a trace from the 5th-Jan insetad. Corrected.

```
15-ene-2010 13:47:03 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para servlet jsp lanzó una excepción
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() ya ha sido llamado para esta respuesta
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:196)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:116)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.inicio2_jsp._jspService(inicio2_jsp.java:300)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.handleAsInclude(PerformForward.java:141)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.perform(PerformForward.java:92)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15-ene-2010 13:47:03 org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExceptionHandler execute
ADVERTENCIA: Unhandled exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: getOutputStream() ya ha sido llamado para esta respuesta
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:367)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.handleAsInclude(PerformForward.java:141)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.perform(PerformForward.java:92)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15-ene-2010 13:47:03 org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ExceptionCatcher postprocess
ADVERTENCIA: Exception from exceptionCommand 'servlet-exception'
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: getOutputStream() ya ha sido llamado para esta respuesta
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:367)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.handleAsInclude(PerformForward.java:141)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.perform(PerformForward.java:92)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15-ene-2010 13:47:03 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet action lanzó excepción
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() ya ha sido llamado para esta respuesta
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:196)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:116)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.inicio2_jsp._jspService(inicio2_jsp.java:300)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.handleAsInclude(PerformForward.java:141)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.perform(PerformForward.java:92)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```