# Spring boot+jasperReports images path error in resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources, jasper-reports

I have spring boot project with jasperReports library.
I have this structure

```
project
          -src
            -main
              -java
                 -my.pakeg
              -resources
                 -static
                   -jasper
                      -images
                         -logo.jpg
                      -rep1.jrxml
                      -rep2.jrxml
                      -rep3.jrxml
                 -templates
```

and in `rep1.jrxml` I include

```
<variable name="tax_logo_repo" class="java.lang.String">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA["images/logo.jpg"]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
```

And I have error `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at: images/logo.jpg.`

But if I move image from `images folder` to `jasper folder`

-resources

```
-static
                   -jasper
                      -images
                         -logo.jpg
                      -logo2.jpg
                      -rep1.jrxml
                      -rep2.jrxml
                      -rep3.jrxml
                 -templates
```

And change this path

```
<variable name="tax_logo_repo" class="java.lang.String">
            <initialValueExpression><![CDATA["logo2.jpg"]]></initialValueExpression>
        </variable>
```

All work fine. Why? I want have images in images folder. How can I do it?

Comment: maybe ../images/logo.jpg

Comment: I tried. It not worked

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5520421/59087

Comment: did you solve your problem?, I have the same problem.