# How does JasperReports engine read subreport path?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I would like to know how report read the path of subreport, because I put the main and sub report in the same folder and I put:

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["subReportname.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

and it doesn't work but when I put the absolute path it works effeciently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JasperReports with a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376725/using-jasperreports-with-a-relative-path)

Comment: @Dave I know how to proceed to add a subreport with a relative path ,but I need to know how does the jasperreport engine reads paths, I'm using ireport. And didn't found the answer in your suggested question