# Link subreport connected to database with mainreport that is sent by controller it won't work even with adding parameter?

Tags: spring-boot, jasper-reports

I have 3 entities orderclient and orderlineclient: relation one-to-many 
and orderlineclient and product: relation many-to-many. I send orderlines to jasper file with this method:

```
@GetMapping("/pdf/{id}")
    public ModelAndView report(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws JRException {


        JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
        view.setUrl("classpath:clientreport.jrxml");
        view.setApplicationContext(appContext);

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

        Client client = clientRepository.findOne(id);
        List<OrderClient> ordersClient = orderClientRepository.findByClient(client);
        List<OrderLineClient> orderLines = new ArrayList<>();

        for (OrderClient order : ordersClient) {
            orderLines.addAll(order.getOrderLineClients());
        }
        params.put("source", orderLines);
        return new ModelAndView(view, params);
        }
```

Then I create a sub-report and I link it directly to the database. After, I create a param and run the following SQL:

```
SELECT product.id,
    product.name,
    product.price,
    order_line_client.id,
    order_line_client.price,
    order_line_client.quantities,
    order_line_client.tooths
FROM product,
    order_line_products,
    order_line_client
WHERE 
     product.id = order_line_products.product_id 
     AND order_line_products.order_line_id = order_line_client.id
     AND order_line_client.order_client_id = $P{orderid}
```

But when I run the app I get exceptions. Can someone please help me get the following:

- date of order
- number of order
- product
- quantities
- price
- totalPrice

  ```
  import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
  import javax.persistence.Entity;
  import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
  import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
  import javax.persistence.Id;
  import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
  import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Objects;

  @Entity

  public class OrderClient {

  // Attributes

  @Id

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

  private Long id;

  private String number;

  private Date orderDate;

  private String notes;

  private String patientName;

  @ManyToOne
  private Client client;

  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "orderClient")
  private List<OrderLineClient> orderLineClients = new ArrayList<>();

  // Getters & Setters

  public Long getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public String getNumber() {
      return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(String number) {
      this.number = number;
  }

  public Date getOrderDate() {
      return orderDate;
  }

  public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
      this.orderDate = orderDate;
  }

  public String getNotes() {
      return notes;
  }

  public void setNotes(String notes) {
      this.notes = notes;
  }

  public String getPatientName() {
      return patientName;
  }

  public void setPatientName(String patientName) {
      this.patientName = patientName;
  }

  public Client getClient() {
      return client;
  }

  public void setClient(Client client) {
      this.client = client;
  }

  public List<OrderLineClient> getOrderLineClients() {
      return orderLineClients;
  }

  public void setOrderLineClients(List<OrderLineClient> orderLineClients) {
      this.orderLineClients = orderLineClients;
  }

  /**
   * equals method
   *
   * @param o
   * @return
   */
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
      OrderClient order = (OrderClient) o;
      return Objects.equals(id, order.id);
  }

  /**
   * hashCode method
   *
   * @return
   */
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(id);
  }
  ```

  }

order line client

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class OrderLineClient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String quantities;

    private Double price;

    private String tooths;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name="orderLine_products", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="orderLine_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id"))
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    private OrderClient orderClient;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getQuantities() {
        return quantities;
    }

    public void setQuantities(String quantities) {
        this.quantities = quantities;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getTooths() {
        return tooths;
    }

    public void setTooths(String tooths) {
        this.tooths = tooths;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public OrderClient getOrderClient() {
        return orderClient;
    }

    public void setOrderClient(OrderClient orderClient) {
        this.orderClient = orderClient;
    }

    public List<Double> getQuantitiesValues(){
        if (getQuantities() == null ) return null;
        if (getQuantities().contains("/"))
            return CollectionUtils.convertList( Arrays.asList(getQuantities().split("/")), s -> Double.parseDouble(s) );
        else {
            return Collections.singletonList(Double.parseDouble(getQuantities()));
        }
    }

    public List<String> getToothsValues(){
        if (getTooths() == null) return null;
        if (getTooths().contains("/"))
            return Arrays.asList(getTooths().split("/"));
        else
            return Collections.singletonList(getTooths());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        OrderLineClient that = (OrderLineClient) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

product

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private Double price;

    private String unit;

    private Double quantity;

    private Double quantityMin;

    private Double quantityMax;

    private String picture;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "products")
    private List<OrderLineClient> orderLineClients = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name="product_category", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="product_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="category_id"))
    private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public Double getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Double quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Double getQuantityMin() {
        return quantityMin;
    }

    public void setQuantityMin(Double quantityMin) {
        this.quantityMin = quantityMin;
    }

    public Double getQuantityMax() {
        return quantityMax;
    }

    public void setQuantityMax(Double quantityMax) {
        this.quantityMax = quantityMax;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(String picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public List<OrderLineClient> getOrderLineClients() {
        return orderLineClients;
    }

    public void setOrderLineClients(List<OrderLineClient> orderLineClients) {
        this.orderLineClients = orderLineClients;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public Category getParentCategory(){
        return getCategories().isEmpty() ? null : getCategories().get(0).getParentCategory();
    }

    public boolean isOneCategory(Category category ){
       return categories.stream().anyMatch(category::equals);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, product.id);
    }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(id);
        }
    }
```

this is the exception

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at: src/main/resources/underreport.jasper.
        at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:153) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:112) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.loadReport(JRFillSubreport.java:402) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:369) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:431) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:345) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:533) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2549) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:791) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:252) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:99) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:609) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:405) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:140) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:667) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:983) ~[jasperreports-6.5.1.jar:6.5.1]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.fillReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:681) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:566) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

this is the main report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="clientreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f5644a3e-c1ef-42f5-b449-e1d38e2d0fd8">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="orderClient.id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="227" y="24" width="100" height="30" uuid="e75f9094-468e-4cf0-83ad-ed751fddd3fd"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Facture]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="241" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-40" y="10" width="615" height="1" uuid="97823373-89aa-42e5-b490-093c4c733c8d"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-40" y="61" width="615" height="1" uuid="0db72487-cd75-44f9-adfa-960ba7228c69"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="71" y="10" width="1" height="51" uuid="361295c4-4882-4557-a9fb-7ebc9cb2f85e"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="167" y="10" width="1" height="51" uuid="d955e6d9-f764-4beb-9dd3-9894d1c63e1b"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="280" y="11" width="1" height="50" uuid="a3695a4f-8c97-416c-8eaf-0969e89928dd"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="fb2c51d1-f35f-4c81-8cb6-26bdfc788bbe">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="a0b6a2a6-515d-45cd-a542-2dc271b1b56f"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[orderClient.id]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="233" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="cacba138-4c84-4a2d-9f82-dd47a2685203">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="a0b6a2a6-515d-45cd-a542-2dc271b1b56f"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderClient.id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="250" y="30" width="200" height="151" uuid="3a4a68df-12fa-4e4b-a3d5-8ba43f819e1d"/>
                <subreportParameter name="orderid">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderClient.id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["src/main/resources/underreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

this is the subreport

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="underreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3365f770-336c-4f9c-a25f-0886872566e0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables">
        <![CDATA[cHJvZHVjdCAsMTM5LDI4LDc0MGI5ZWIxLTY4OGYtNGI3MS1hOGVjLWY3NDA0ZWE2ZmIzOTtvcmRl
cl9saW5lX3Byb2R1Y3RzICwyMzUsNDEsZWY1N2VmY2EtZDNmYS00MTNhLWE0MTgtNzA5ODU2ZWEz
YTQ0O29yZGVyX2xpbmVfY2xpZW50ICwxNSwxNSxmOTdiYTY2OC03MTNiLTQzNzAtYWI0MS1kODFi
YmM4MGFiZTE7]]>
    </property>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="JDBC Data Adapter"/>
    <parameter name="orderid" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT product.id,
    product.name,
    product.price,
    order_line_client.id,
    order_line_client.price,
    order_line_client.quantities,
    order_line_client.tooths
FROM product,
    order_line_products,
    order_line_client
WHERE 
     product.id = order_line_products.product_id 
     AND order_line_products.order_line_id = order_line_client.id]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="product"/>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="name"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="product"/>
    </field>
    <field name="price" class="java.lang.Double">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="price"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="product"/>
    </field>
    <field name="COLUMN_4" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="order_line_client"/>
    </field>
    <field name="COLUMN_5" class="java.lang.Double">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="price"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="order_line_client"/>
    </field>
    <field name="quantities" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="quantities"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="order_line_client"/>
    </field>
    <field name="tooths" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="tooths"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="order_line_client"/>
    </field>
    <group name="id">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="name">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="price">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="COLUMN_4">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_4}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="COLUMN_5">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_5}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="quantities">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantities}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="tooths">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{tooths}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4d24ee13-0586-4ab5-8804-0f984acdd187">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="0e5824f5-b3da-4bba-88b6-b57f5fb9d886"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="616ff217-cfb2-496c-bbb8-0f4ee2a644b8">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="0e5824f5-b3da-4bba-88b6-b57f5fb9d886"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: i add exception and jrxml code

Comment: This is probably a problem with the paths being used. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5520421/59087 for an example of using a relative path for subreports.

Comment: i add paramater but i got another exceptions  :cvc-complex-type.3.2.2 : L'attribut 'ROOT_DIR' n'est pas autorisé dans l'élément 'parameter'

Comment: Alors, demande un autre question, svp.